# undefined is not a function (evaluating 't.matches(e)')

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm working on this huge Angular 7 application and I get this error message often. I can't find a common pattern in terms of browsers or devices. I'm completely unable to reproduce it in any way. I just know it comes from the vendor bundle in my Angular application. The error stack is ridiculously long:

```
{
  "agent": "OS: Other 0.0.0 | Browser: Other 0.0.0 | Device: Other 0.0.0",
  "message": "undefined is not a function (evaluating 't.matches(e)')",
  "name": "TypeError",
  "stack": [
    {
      "functionName": "p",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 1545102
    },
    {
      "functionName": "matchesElement",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 2455780
    },
    {
      "functionName": "processLeaveNode",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 2401262
    },
    {
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 2404500
    },
    {
      "functionName": "forEach",
      "fileName": "[native code]"
    },
    {
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 2403630
    },
    {
      "functionName": "flush",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 2401969
    },
    {
      "functionName": "flush",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 2430767
    },
    {
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 5516078
    },
    {
      "functionName": "runOutsideAngular",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 1124396
    },
    {
      "functionName": "end",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 5516029
    },
    {
      "functionName": "detectChanges",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 1231766
    },
    {
      "functionName": "onLoad",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/13.2af2a89cea99f16973a1.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 100745
    },
    {
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/13.2af2a89cea99f16973a1.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 106764
    },
    {
      "functionName": "handleEvent",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 768774
    },
    {
      "functionName": "handleEvent",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 1285260
    },
    {
      "functionName": "km",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 738539
    },
    {
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 760144
    },
    {
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 1445303
    },
    {
      "functionName": "__tryOrUnsub",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 1708959
    },
    {
      "functionName": "next",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 1708112
    },
    {
      "functionName": "_next",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 1137637
    },
    {
      "functionName": "next",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 1137309
    },
    {
      "functionName": "next",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 2097465
    },
    {
      "functionName": "emit",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 1054418
    },
    {
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 410979
    },
    {
      "functionName": "__tryOrUnsub",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 1708959
    },
    {
      "functionName": "next",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 1708112
    },
    {
      "functionName": "_next",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 1137637
    },
    {
      "functionName": "next",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 1137309
    },
    {
      "functionName": "notifyNext",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 134811
    },
    {
      "functionName": "_next",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 3398167
    },
    {
      "functionName": "next",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 1137309
    },
    {
      "functionName": "_next",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 5725720
    },
    {
      "functionName": "next",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 1137309
    },
    {
      "functionName": "_next",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 1137637
    },
    {
      "functionName": "next",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 1137309
    },
    {
      "functionName": "_next",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 472258
    },
    {
      "functionName": "next",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 1137309
    },
    {
      "functionName": "_next",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 5725720
    },
    {
      "functionName": "next",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 1137309
    },
    {
      "functionName": "notifyNext",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 5058132
    },
    {
      "functionName": "_next",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 3398167
    },
    {
      "functionName": "next",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 1137309
    },
    {
      "functionName": "onload",
      "fileName": "https://www.my-website.com/vendor.45b0d2a7efb1304d4f27.js",
      "lineNumber": 1,
      "columnNumber": 324844
    }
  ]
}
```

Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Comment: Are you debugging in AOT mode?
When I debug I'm using JIT with source maps and the stack trace is quite precise.

Comment: This error is happening in several different clients in production (therefore in AOT mode) and I'm not able to reproduce it myself. I'm just getting the error reported back to our servers through my error handler.

Comment: I got errors like this on 20th - 22th of september, so very close to when you asked this question... probably some dependecy that both of us use caused it? Do you have any news on these errors @RTYX?

Comment: I have no news :( After some deep debugging (kind of unsuccessful) I have the theory it has something to do with `*ngFor` and `trackBy`. I removed my `trackBy` functions some days ago and I haven't seen the error again, but still was not able to reproduce it in any case, so can't be really sure.

Comment: Did that fix your issue?